# Why the <div> is not getting removed after clicking on image and why the image is getting removed in following case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having many `<div class="rbt"></div>` present on my webpage and each of these `<div>`'s contains an icon to delete that `<div>` only from which the icon is clicked. But what's happening is the respective `<div>` is not getting deleted and the cross button image gets hide. I've created one jsFiddle to demonstrate my issue but in jsFiddle the image is not getting hide as well as the `<div>` is also not getting deleted. Can some one please help me in this regard?
HTML code is:

```
<div class="col-md-10 rebate_block">             
  <div class="rbt">
    <div style="overflow:auto" class="well">                 
      </br>
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="blacklistgrid_1"  class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Products</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Pack Of</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Quantity</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Volume</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Unit</th>
              <th style="vertical-align:middle">Rebate Amount</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody class="apnd-test">
            <tr id="reb1_1">
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <select name="product_id_1[1]" id="product_id_1_1" class="form-control prod_list">
                    <option value=""  selected='selected'>Select Product</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="pack[1]" id="pack_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="quantity[1]" id="quantity_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="volume[1]" id="volume_1" value="" class="form-control" size="8"/>
              </td>
              <td>
                <div class="btn-group">
                  <select name="units[1]" id="units_1" class="form-control">
                    <option value="" selected='selected'>Select Unit</option>
                    <option value="5" >Microsecond</option>       
                    <option value="7" >oz</option>       
                    <option value="9" >ml</option>       
                    <option value="10" >L</option>       
                    <option value="12" >gms</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="text" name="amount[1]" id="amount_1" value="" class="form-control" size="9"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        <tfoot>

        <tr id="reb1_2">
          <td>
            <button style="float:right; margin-bottom: 20px" class="products" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="">&nbsp;Add</button>
          </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>                                           
  </table>                  
</div>                                
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Rebate Start Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input class="form-control date_control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_start_date[1]" id="rebate_start_date_1" value="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Expiry Date<span style="color:#FF0000">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <input class="form-control date_control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date" name="rebate_expiry_date[1]" id="rebate_expiry_date_1" value="">
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-5">Applicable States</label>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
      <select class="states" multiple="multiple" name="applicable_states[1][]" id="applicable_states_1">
        <option value="1">Alabama</option>
        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
        // ... other states as options
        <option value="49">Wisconsin</option>
        <option value="50">Wyoming</option>                                          
      </select>                          
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <label for="name" class="col-lg-6">Rebate Total Count</label>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rebate_total_count[1]" id="rebate_total_count_1" value="">
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
  <div style="float: clear;"></div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-2"></div>
    <div align="right" class="col-xs-5">
      <button style='color:#C00; opacity: 2;margin-right: -12px;' type='button' class='close del_reb' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
    </div>                
  </div>
  </div> <!-- /span8 --></div>
</div>
```

jQuery code is:

```
$(function () {
  //function to delete rebate entry(i.e. entire rebate block) in add rebate by product   
  $(document).delegate('.del_reb','click',function (event) {   
    $(this).parents('.rbt').remove(); 
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

[**`js Fiddle link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/3Fkf3/1/)

Comment: the delete functionality is working fine here,http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/3Fkf3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you have not attached any jquery library in your fiddle..just attach any of the jquery library from dropdown and try again

[image]

Demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/3Fkf3/6/

```
$(function () {
  //function to delete rebate entry(i.e. entire rebate block) in add rebate by product   
  $(document).delegate('.del_reb','click',function (event) {   
    $(this).parents('.rbt').remove(); 
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

According to ur comments you are using jquery 1.9 so I would request you to take a look here :- As suggested by official jquery site http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

> As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method.
>   For earlier versions, however, it remains the most effective means to
>   use event delegation. More information on event binding and delegation
>   is in the .on() method. In general, these are the equivalent templates
>   for the two methods:
>
> // jQuery 1.4.3+
>
> $( elements ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );
>
> // jQuery 1.7+
>
> $( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );

Comment: But I've added jQuery library to my form. WHy there it's not working?

Comment: make sure that jquery library included before your own code

Comment: which version of jquery you are using @PHPLover?

Comment: @Neel:I'm using jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: Why don't you use .on instead of that..have a look here they suggested to use .on http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_delegate.asp @PHPLover